# @auth0/angular-jwt: Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'JwtModule' was called

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt, auth0

I upgraded my Angular project from 9 to 10 (and upgrading `angular-jwt` to version 5.0.1), and the Angular Library that I've built does not compile anymore. Instead, it returns an error:

> ERROR: Error during template compile of 'NAME OF LIBRARY MODULE'
> Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'JwtModule' was called.

I did not change the code related to JwtModule whatsoever, but for some reason, `JwtModule.forRoot(<my config object>)` is not accepted anymore in the imports of my library module. If I remove the `.forRoot(...)` part, my library compiles. But then, I miss my JwtOptions config. As far as I know, using `.forRoot()` is the only way to make sure that the JwtModule is a singleton, with the same config applied everywhere.

Is this an issue with implementations that break when upgrading to Angular 10, or am I simply missing something?

### My library module

```
// the JWT module, for ensuring the JWT is managed properly
import { JwtModule, JwtModuleOptions } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
// ... more imports in reality

// exported function for the jwt service..
export function jwtTokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
}
const jwtConfig : JwtModuleOptions = {
  config: {
    headerName: 'Jwt-Authorization',
    tokenGetter: jwtTokenGetter,
    allowedDomains: [ 'api.vvtupos.nl', 'login.vvtupos.nl' ]
  }
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ... more declarations in reality
  ],
  imports: [
    JwtModule.forRoot(jwtConfig)
    // ... more imports in reality
  ],
  exports: [
    // ... more exports in reality
  ]
})
export class ClubcoreLibraryModule {
  constructor(){
  }
}
```

Comment: It would make a terrible answer, given the official advice, but for me, changing `enableIvy` to `true` did the trick. As a commenter on a [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14707) pointed out, issues like this are solved by Ivy. But then, for libraries, you'd need to first build the library. I did have `enableIvy` set to `false`, so I did not make use of Ivy in my library (and you shouldn't for NPM-published libraries!), so for me, with my private library in an Angular 10 project, it did the trick!

Comment: Hence, I'm not solving this question with my answer. Maybe when advice changes (whenever Ivy is recommended for libraries by the Angular team), the above comment becomes a more universal solution.